# Is my mysql database vulnerable to attack if I've posted a php file containing the database user pw?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I posted a php file that I just realized contains the password for connecting to the mysql database, in the form of a mysqli_connect. Am I now vulnerable to an attack?

Comment: posted the code to the public? then yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,change your password immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better change the password, just in case someone gets it and tries to do something nasty.

Of course it is difficult that someone gets access to your server, etc, but it is better not to worry for things like that. Just change the password and feel safe again.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your database is also accessible from outside your server, probably not much more than you would have been otherwise. In order to connect to the database, someone would (hopefully) have to connect to your server first. When he's there, he may as well read the connection credentials out of the source code stored there.

It's not a bad idea to change the password anyway.

Comment: That of course depends on whether the server and database have sufficiently different passwords, not always the case.

Comment: Of course. If `database password` also `=== server password`, all hope is lost...